# React Javascript: Render current week by index giving 32, 33,34

Tags: javascript, react-native, datetime

I am using react native. I am not that great at javascript. I am trying to render the current week days like 1 ,2, 3 using the index added on to the day of the current week. However when the end of the month is reached I am getting 32,33,34,35 for my dates as well as months that have 28 , 30 and 31 days mixed up.

Please may someone help me . I am not that great at javascript so I am finding it hard to understand where I am going wrong

**This is what I am trying to do with the days of the current week:**

```
let curr;
let Monday;
let Sunday;

const CurrentWeek = () =>{
let days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ]

    let curr = new Date; // get current date
    var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    var last = first + 7; // last day is the first day + 6
    Monday = new Date(curr.setDate(first))
    Sunday = new Date(curr.setDate(last))
    curr = Monday;


const renderItem = ({item, index}) =>{
    return(
        <View>
        <Text>{item}</Text>

        {/* I have a problem here because when the month has 31 days it adds to 
        the current week of Monday and the dates will end up being 32 ,33,34,35. 
        I don't know how to fix this line using index */}
        <Text >{new Date(Monday).getDate() + index}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
return(
    <View>
        <FlatList
            data ={days}
            horizontal
            keyExtractor = {(item)=>item}
            renderItem = {renderItem}
        />
    </View>
)
}
```

Comment: *first* will be Sunday, not Monday, as weekdays are numbered from 0 for Sunday to 6 for Saturday. After setting *Sunday*, *curr* is set to the same date. `new Date(Monday).getDate()` is inefficient, `Monday.getDate()` will give exactly the same result.

Comment: Thank you so how can I fix this because when the end of the month is reached because of the way I am obtaining the index from the flat list I am getting the days like 32,33,34 when it is supposed to switch to 1 after 31 or 30. So how do I tackle that ?

Comment: Likely it's a consequence of `{new Date(Monday).getDate() + index}`, try adding index to the Date before getting the date: `{new Date(Monday.setDate(Monday.getDate() + index)).getDate()}` so that say 27 Feb + 3 will give 3 Mar.

Comment: The expression can be rewritten as `{(new Date(+Monday + index * DAY)).getDate()}` where `DAY = 24*60*60*1000` (1 day in milliseconds)

Comment: @Vitalii—that will have difficult to find bugs in places where daylight saving is used as some days are more than 24 hours long (and some are shorter). The *set/getDate* method avoids that.